# Is a scissor mechanism considered a parallel manipulator

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanisms

According to Wikipedia (I know) a parallel manipulator is a single end effector driven by several serial chains. Does this include a simple scissor lift mechanism? And is there a better definition of what a parallel mechanism actually is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A parallel mechanism is one where multiple "chains" connect the moved part to the ground.  The parallel portion references that each chain (really a set of actuators and linkages) can move separately at the same time, and each is required to move in separately to achieve the desired platform orientation.

Your two legs are a parallel mechanism.  For a dog, its 4 legs are a parallel mechanism.

A serial mechanism is a single leg - it extends, retracts, and twists to provide the needed input to the body.  The position of each joint is dependent on the supporting joint.

A scissor lift is really just a simple mechanical advantage device that lifts a platform up and down only.  We could define it as a limited version of a parallel mechanism where the 2 serial mechanisms are linked, but I don't think the definition fits well.